# How to remove multiple keys from a map?

Tags: clojure

I have a function that removes a key from a map:

```
(defn remove-key [key map]
  (into {}
        (remove (fn [[k v]] (#{key} k))
                map)))

(remove-key :foo {:foo 1 :bar 2 :baz 3})
```

How do i apply this function using multiple keys?

```
(remove-keys [:foo :bar] {:foo 1 :bar 2 :baz 3})
```

I have an implementation using loop...recur. Is there a more idiomatic way of doing this in Clojure?

```
(defn remove-keys [keys map]
  (loop [keys keys
         map map]
    (if (empty? keys)
      map
      (recur (rest keys) (remove-key (first keys) map)))))
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Your `remove-key` function is covered by the standard library function `dissoc`. `dissoc` will remove more than one key at a time, but it wants the keys to be given directly in the argument list rather than in a list. So you can use `apply` to "flatten" it out.

```
(apply dissoc {:foo 1, :bar 2, :baz 3} [:foo :bar])
==> {:baz 3}
```

Answer (score 48):

[`dissoc`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/dissoc) removes one or more keys from a map:

```
(dissoc {:foo 1 :bar 2 :baz 3} :foo :bar)
```

or, if you have the keys in a collection

```
(apply dissoc {:foo 1 :bar 2 :baz 3} [:foo :bar])
```

Comment: Doesn't Clojure have a way to "explode" a vector in a function call? ala Python's `*list`?

Comment: @john2x, `apply` does exactly that.  I.e., `(apply f foo bar baz)` is equivalent to `f(foo bar *baz)` in python.

Comment: The vector form did not work for me.  I did the following (strings for keys):
`(dissoc map "foo" "bar" )`

Answer (score 11):

As others said use the built-in function instead of writing your own.

However, if this was just an example and you want an answer of how to do that if there wasn't a standard dissoc, then you can use:

```
(reduce (fn [m k] (remove-key k m)) {:foo 1 :bar 2 :baz 3} [:foo :bar])
```

Obviously, if you revert the arguments to remove-key it can be written much simpler:

```
(reduce remove-key {:foo 1 :bar 2 :baz 3} [:foo :bar])
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this type of thing and others to be super annoying in clojure, so to fix it I created the library instar: https://github.com/boxed/instar .